# Digital Signatures - What is the optimal size of the seed data to sign

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am planning to use digital signatures to authenticate the clients calling my MVC 4.0 Web API services.  In the ASP.NET 3.5 client I will use a certificate to create a digital signature and put it in the Authorization header.

I was wondering what size should the data be (when I say data, I mean the string that I use to generate the signature). Is this important?

Also is it good practice to change this seed data each time I generate the signature - i.e by including the current date time in it.

I have been looking at this:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A digital signature can be thought as follows:

```
SignatureValue = EncryptWithPrivateKey(DigestOf(data))
```

Since Digital Signature is applied on Digest Value of the data, its Length is not that important.